# angularJs loop not working in controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory

I cant use loops on my controller and no error
this is my code

```
'use strict';

var chartApp = angular.module('chartsApp');

chartApp.controller('chartController', ['$scope', 'ChartingService', function($scope, ChartingService){

var charts = ChartingService.query();
console.log(charts);

for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    console.log(charts[i]);
};


console.log('after');

}]);
```

and this is the cose to get the data from api

```
var app = angular.module('chartsApp');

app.factory('ChartingService', function($resource) {
return $resource('/api/sales', {
    id: '@id'
}, {
    add: {method: 'POST'}

});
});
```

i dont get any error but the loop arnt working
when i console log the var charts its printing on the console window all the data

thats what i get in the console

[image: http://prntscr.com/9lkb5y]

any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation of $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) says:

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an **empty** reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

(emphasis mine)

And then follows an example which uses a callback function in order to get the first element of the array returned by `query()`, **once it's available**.

Comment: This guy is telling the truth. :) You should really understand how javascript promises are working. Obviously you don't have the data when you try to go over it with the for loop... But later it'll. So that's why u can see it with your console.

Comment: ok but why it prints the data on the console and cant loop the data?

Comment: What does it print in the console?

Comment: all the data
array of charts data

Comment: I doubt it. Edit your question, and add **exactly** what is printed in the console. Verbatim.

Comment: I have honestly no idea how this is printed. What is sure is that the promise is not resolved yet at the time you're printing, and that the length of the "array" is still 0. Maybe the browser displays the content of the array asynchronously and happens to show the values downloaded and stored in the "array", although the promise hasn't been resolved yet at the moment console.log() is called, and the length hasn't been updated yet.